# Querying google news using C#

Tags: javascript, c#

I am using Google news API to retrieve google news by passing city and country names by sending query string. But I want to have news in categories for example Pakistan sports. What query should I pass ??
For regular news I am using  HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://news.google.com/news?q=" + NewsParameters + "&output=rss");
where NewsParameters= city and country name. and its working

for specific news I am using
https://news.google.com/news/section?cf=all&ned="+countryCode+"&topic=e&siidp=a2d4639994c2816260651ff9a5cb9b92ea8b&ict=ln"
where countryCode= country short form that appears in query string i.e. for Australia its au and topic=e tells us its about entertainment.